# UITableView inside UIView in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have a problem when put a **UITableView** into **UIView**.

I set a **delegate** and **datasource** and implement all methods.

This is my UIView Class.

```
@objc class ChooserView: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var backgroundView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var showView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!    

public class func createChooserView() -> ChooserView {

    var view: ChooserView!
    view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: ChooserView.self), owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! ChooserView

    _ = MLAutolayouts.fillContainer(UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.subviews.first!, view: view)

    //Register cell nib
    view.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PhoneCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PhoneCell")

    return view
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: PhoneCell.self)) as! PhoneCell

    return cell
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("TAP...")
   } 
}
```

And this is the **outles**

[image]

When run my app. I get this error

```
   -[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fded2e772d0
```

Log img.

[image]

Any idea...

Thanks.

Comment: You've declared your class in code, but looks like you forgot to declare that your view in IB has type of your class, that's why you see `-[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]` instead of `-[ChooserView ...`

Comment: How to connect the UIView?? @Hasham

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Connect IB of dataSource and delegate to ChooserView instead of any other view.

Just right click on your table view and 
Follow the attached gif for connecting IB properly :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have applied outlets from storyboard and you are  specifying in code as well .There is no need of that.Secondly is there any custom class for your table that contains label or button?This issue generally occurs if u have missed any IBoutlet connection with storyboard or specified 2 connection for a same outlet check it once.

Comment: Hi josueh connect your uiview in similar way as u did for table view.